# Automatically transfer data on certain conditions

Tags: vba, excel

It's my first time using this website and I'd greatly appreciate if someone could help me write a code for Macro in Excel to do the following.

Situation:

1. I have 8 data sheets called `Data A`, `Data B`, ..., `Data H`.
2. I have 1 summary sheet called `Summary`.
3. On each of 8 data sheets, there are *n* number of IDs from cell `C8` and on horizontally (i.e. `C8`, `D8`, `E8`, ...) .
4. Each ID has associated data under the cells vertically. (i.e. ID in cell `C8` has relevant data on `C9`, `C10`, `C13`, `C14`, `C15`).

To do:

1. Upon activating macro, go to `Data A`, start from `C8` to check if the cell is empty or not.
2. If the cell is not empty, copy the ID (a string and number combination) in cell `C8` along with relevant data from (`C9` to `C10`) and (`C13` to `C15`) onto `Summary` sheet at (`A1` to `A6`).
3. After copying, move to the next cell which is `D8` on `Data A` sheet, repeat step 2. This time, the destination of copying would be `B1` to `B6` on `Summary` sheet.
4. At any point, if a cell on row 8 on `Data A` sheet is empty, move to next data sheet (`Data B`).
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 until an empty cell is found on `Data H` sheet.

I hope I could find someone who would be able to do this.

Here is what I have so far (please understand I'm a beginner in VBA):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim r As Integer

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "Data *" Then
            With ws
               'Assign a value to each character
                Dim AscCode As Short
                AscCode = Asc("A")

            End With

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: why are you skipping C11 and C12? Is that part of the macro for all rows?

Comment: What do you have so far?  Typically here you're expected to at least have __something__ before people will help...

Comment: @ Raystafarian: The sections I'd like to copy are located separately such as C9 to C10 and C13 to C15. The macro would search the specific row, one by one horizontally, but stops when the cell is empty.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Sorry I didn't know the typical expectation. Thank you for letting me know. I will post what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub CopyToSummary()

Dim arrSheets, i As Integer
Dim rngId As Range, rngSummary As Range

    arrSheets = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", _
                      "E", "F", "G", "H")

    Set rngSummary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1")

    For i = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)

        Set rngId = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data " & arrSheets(i)).Range("C8")
        Do While Len(rngId.Value) > 0

            With rngSummary
                .Value = rngId.Value
                .Offset(1, 0).Value = rngId.Offset(1, 0).Value
                'etc for the other values
            End With

            Set rngSummary = rngSummary.Offset(0, 1)
            Set rngId = rngId.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @user1195453: You might then want to accept Tim's answer then? See this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113393/accepting-answers